# jQuery Datepicker only show Mondays and disable certain Mondays

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, user-interface, datepicker

I'm having trouble trying to combine only showing Mondays as well as disabling specific dates on the beforeShowDay parameter of the jQuery datepicker... I want the user to only be able to select Mondays, except for 2/20/2012 and 2/27/2012 but am not sure how to implement this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var unavailableDates = ["20-02-2012", "27-12-2012"];
        function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = (date.getDay() == 1);
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: unavailable,
            minDate: 0
          });
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the passed in date with another date object. Instead, you're comparing it with items in an array of strings.

I would use `valueOf` or `getTime`, which return the number of milliseconds since 01 January UTC to make the comparison:

```JavaScript
var unavailableDates = [
    new Date(2012, 1, 20).valueOf(),
    new Date(2012, 1, 27).valueOf()
];

function unavailable(date) {
    if (date.getDay() === 1 && $.inArray(date.valueOf(), unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aThZG/

Comment: Great, this is working perfectly. I do have one question, though. How come the following is disabling the 20th and 27th of February when the month specified is January (1)? `new Date(2012, 1, 20).valueOf()`

Comment: Because the `month` argument of the `Date` constructor is 0-based. See the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) docs for more info.